# how to add a new tab in spree admin panel?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, spree

I created a controller under Spree::Admin module and also I have mentioned in

routes.rb

```
match '/admin/new_tab => 'spree/admin/new_controller#index'
```

but this is working in front end.

How can I move this page to admin panel with new tab?

Comment: The fact that it's accessible without login (if that's what you meant) is a controller thing. You should do some kind of validation there and check that in fact, an Admin is logged. I haven't worked with Spree, but I guess you should be inheriting from their base controller.

Then, the "admin panel", is probably just a layout. You apply whatever Spree layout is to your views. Don't know if this is supposed to be done by hand or not in Spree though.

Answer (score 4):

To make this controller work only if admin is signed in (like the other controllers in `Admin` namespace), it should inherit from `Admin::BaseController`. 
To make the new tab, you should probably create `Deface`, something like this:

```
Deface::Override.new(:virtual_path => "spree/layouts/admin",
    :name => "admin_content_admin_tab_parser",
    :insert_bottom => "[data-hook='admin_tabs']",
    :text => "<%= tab :new_tab,  :url => 'admin/new_tab', :icon => 'icon-th-large' %>",
    :disabled => false)
```

Comment: Marek, you have mentioned `<%= tab :new_tab ...`. What would be the view to the tab? I mean, as I understand your code will add a tab to the view. My question is when it is selected, which view would be loaded? Is it `admin/new_tab` html ?

Comment: I can't say what view will be loaded. Action from `/admin/new_tab` path will simply be called.

Comment: So it is kind of been routed to `/admin/new_tab` ?

Comment: @ZiyanJunaideen it's simple link to `/admin/new_tab`.

Comment: Marek, what is the :new_tab parameter passed? I am getting an error like `undefined method 'admin_new_tab_path' for #<ActionDispatch::Routing::RoutesProxy:0xc82d7bc>`

Comment: @ZiyanJunaideen
I guess you should create appropriate action and route.
What version of `Spree` do you use? In 1.3.2 it should work if you pass `:url` option explicitly.

Comment: I was using `:match_route` instead of `:url` as I was looking in to how spree has implemented some thing similar. I missed it from your example. Thanks. Might need your help later so will move this to 'chat'...

Comment: FYI, if anyone comes upon this code in the future, as of Spree v2.1.2, the virtual_path should be `"spree/admin/shared/_menu"`.